# django - save a resize copy of image on upload (using admin site)

Tags: django, image, image-processing, admin, thumbnails

I'm building a site for a client that needs to support image uploads (an artist) through the admin interface. Since most of the images are pretty high-res, I wanted to create thumb copies of the image to display on the gallery page after the upload. The upload works great with the forms.ImageFile element, but I was looking for some ideas on how to do the actual resizing and and linking between the thumb and the true size images. I had an idea to hold model class for both an image and an image thumb:

```
from django.db import models

class Image(models.Model):
    """a true size image"""
    image = models.ImageFile(upload_to="images")
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "images"

class ImageThumb(models.Model):
    """"a thumbnail of an actual image"""
    real_image = models.ForeignKey('Image')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/thumbs")

    class Meta:
        db_table = "thumbs"
```

That part I'm stuck on is how to resize the real image after upload (pil? how?), and I could probably use some polishing on my models - any help will be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a great plugin called [sorl-thumbnail](http://code.google.com/p/sorl-thumbnail/) that deals with thumbnail generation - don't bother doing it yourself. sorl-thumbnail is very configurable, so the chances are it'll do anything you want it to do.

If that doesn't work for you, then [photologue](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/) is also very good (photologue is more tailored towards managing photo albums, rather than just plain thumbnail generation).

Answer (score 0):

See also [easy-thumbnails](http://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails) and [aino-convert](http://bitbucket.org/aino/aino-convert/src). They might be a good bet since sorl-thumbnail [might not be developed very actively from now on](http://code.google.com/p/sorl-thumbnail/wiki/Future).